# How to use custom emoji in telegram bot

Tags: python, html, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

We have created a simple telegram bot using telegram api that sends short messages occasionally to users. we desire to include a custom emoji in its messages. regarding to latest telegram update version 6.2 it's possible. So any idea how can we do that? pls atach an example which can be used in parsmode 'html'

In fact we need an "html tag" to attach our custom emojis in a message. We didn't find these tags where ever we searched for them. Anyone can give a hand ?

Comment: Custom emoji? Do you mean those stickers?

Comment: @0stone0 No sir I mean the new custom animated emojjs.